# Area inside outer curve of limacon $r=1+2\cos\theta$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

I need to find the area inside the outer curve of limacon $r=1+2\cos\theta$

Here is what I tried:
$$
0=1+2\cos\theta
$$
$$
\theta=\cos^{-1}(-\frac{1}{2})
$$
$$
\theta=\frac{2}{3}\pi  ,  \theta=\frac{8}{3}\pi
$$
$$
A = 2\int^{\frac{8}{2}\pi}_{\frac{2}{3}\pi}r^2d\theta=\frac{r^3}{3}|^{\frac{8}{3}\pi}_{\frac{2}{3}\pi}=2\frac{(1+2\cos\theta)^3}{3}|^{\frac{8}{3}\pi}_{\frac{2}{3}\pi}=0
$$
so, 0 area is clearly wrong. Where was my mistake?

Comment: why don't replace $r^2$ with its expression ($1+2cos(\theta)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer curve of the limacon lies between $\theta=\pm\frac{2\pi}{3}$ but using symmetry it is twice the area between $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{3}$

[image: limacon]
\begin{eqnarray}
A&=&2\int_0^{2\pi/3}\frac{1}{2}r^2d\theta\\
&=&\int_0^{2\pi/3}(1+2\cos\theta)^2d\theta\\
&=&\int_0^{2\pi/3}3+4\cos\theta+2\cos(2\theta)\,d\theta
=[3\theta+4\sin\theta+\sin(2\theta)]_0^{2\pi/3}\\
&=&2\pi+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks. How did you find the correct bounds?

Comment: Sketch the graph $y=1+2\cos x$ in rectangular coordinates. The outer loop will correspond to the portion of the curve lying above the $x$-axis. You can clearly see from the rectangular version of the graph that it is above the $x$-axis between $-\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Comment: When graphing polar curves it's sometimes helpful to first graph the rectangular version replacing $r$ with $y$ and $\theta$ with $x$. When $y=0$ the polar curve is at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

You pretended that the $d\theta$ was a $dr$. Unfortunately you cannot do that.
$$2\int^{\frac{8}{2}\pi}_{\frac{2}{3}\pi}r^2d\theta\color{red}{\neq}\frac{r^3}{3}|^{\frac{8}{3}\pi}_{\frac{2}{3}\pi}$$
Now I'll let you try it. If you still need help, just ask!

Answer (score 0):

$\int\limits_{\theta = 0}^{2 \pi} (1 + 2 \cos (\theta )\ d \theta = 2 \pi$.